# Are string literals null-terminated?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, string-literals, null-terminated

Which of the following are null-terminated string?

```
char *str1 = "This is a string.";
char *str2 = "This is a string.\0";
char str3[] = "This is a string.";
const char *str4 = "This is a string.";
const char *str5 = "This is a string.\0";
const char str6[] = "This is a string.";
```

Comment: "I am always null terminated."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- All : a string literal is a null terminated string
- `str2` and `str5` have the particularity of being *doubly null-terminated* strings

Also :

- `char *str1` should be `const char *str1`
- `char *str2` should be `const char *str2`

Comment: Your're wrong about the last one (str3). It's a valid array initialization.

Answer (score 9):

They are all null-terminated (`str2` and `str5` are actually doubly-null-terminated) because using double quotes is a shorthand for a null-terminated char array.

So this:

```
"Hello"
```

Is actually this:

```
{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}
```

Variables pointing to string literals such as these should be declared as `const`.

Answer (score 1):

All. C compiler auto aggregates string with a terminate '\0', then store it in a char[] or refer to it by char *;

Answer (score -3):

Don't use `char*s="hi"` in case you want to do something with the string like modifying it or even if you want to concatenate something to it because here string`hi`is in read only section of the memory and your program can crash