# wrong output from strcpy function in for loop

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main() {
    char questions[][100] = {"1. what year did the c language debut?:",
                             "2. who is credited with crating c?:",
                             "3. what is the predecossor of c?:"};
    
    char options[][100] = {"a. 1969","b. 1972","c. 1975","d. 1999",
                           "a. dennis r.","b. nikola tesla","c. john carmarck","d. doc b.",
                           "a. objective c","b. b","c. c++","d. c#"};
    
    char answers[3] = {'b','a','b'};
    
    int numberofquestions = sizeof(questions) / sizeof(questions[0]);
    char space[] = "                         ";
    char guess[numberofquestions];
    char results[3][7];
    int score = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numberofquestions * 4; i++){
        strncat(options[i], space, 25 - strlen(options[i]));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numberofquestions; i++){
        printf("\n%s\n", questions[i]);
    
        for(int j = 4 * i; j < 4 * (i + 1); j++){
            printf("%s", options[j]);
        }
    
        printf("\n\nguess: ");
        scanf("%c", &guess[i]);
        scanf("%*c"); // this is for clearing \n from input buffer, * for ??
        
        if(guess[i] == answers[i]){
            score++;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numberofquestions; i++){
        if(guess[i] == answers[i]){
            strcpy(results[i], "correct");
        }
        else{
            strcpy(results[i], "wrong");
        }
    }
    printf("\n1st question is %s\n", results[0]);
    printf("2nd question is %s\n", results[1]);
    printf("3rd question is %s\n", results[2]);
    
    printf("\ntotal score is %d/%d", score, numberofquestions);
    return 0;

}
```

W
hen I run the code with the correct answers 'b', 'a', and 'b' i get the output

```
1st question is correctcorrectcorrect
2nd question is correctcorrect
3rd question is correct

total score is 3/3
```

but if I run with the wrong answers I get the output

```
1st question is wrong
2nd question is wrong
3rd question is wrong

total score is 0/3
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the rationale for null terminated strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418708/whats-the-rationale-for-null-terminated-strings)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `char results[3][7];`, how did you decide on those sizes?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that your results buffer `char results[3][7]` isn't big enough.

[C strings are NULL terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395991/null-terminated-string) which means that each string literal needs an extra `char` to mark the end.

So, the literal `"wrong"` actually has length 6, and `"correct"` has length 8.

The entries in `results` are arranged consecutively in memory, so when you copy `"correct"` into `results[i]` the null terminating character spills into the space for `results[i+1][0]`. When `results[i+1]` is copied into place it overwrites that character.

You can fix this here by increasing the size of the buffers: `char results[3][8]`.